# ERROR 1064 (42000) For creating a table in MariaDB

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I am getting an error for my mysql query and I have no idea why. I am following exactly what is in my sql programming book and couldn't figure it out online either.

I appreciate any help!

````
CREATE TABLE account (
    `ID` varcahr(5) NOT NULL ,
    `Names` varchar(30) NULL,
    `Balance` decimal(10,2) NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);```
````

Comment: Please tick the answer if that works for you.  The post has been closed as it has no value to future visitors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write

```
`ID` varchar(5) NOT NULL
```

instead

```
`ID` varcahr(5) NOT NULL
```